# Google map infowindow is offset by 2px

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the standard `infoWindow` dialog. However there is a 2px offset where the speech bubble and arrow meet:

[image: google map offset]

Any reason this might be happening?

This is a sample of the code I'm using:

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var contentString = '<p>Content Here</p>';
    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Comment: `Any reason this might be happening?` - css issue.

Comment: We really need to see the real thing. (Otherwise, it's like sending a photo of yourself to the doctor to get a diagnosis.)